# how do i make a flashlight in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to make a horror game and need to get the flashlight to work, but when i use the spot it doesn't show up. I am in BGE, i don't want to use any of the other light sources because they don't give me what i want

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/what-will-happen-with-blender-2-8-game-engine/106988

Comment: Did you enabled GLSL material mode (Render tab)? Spot lights don't work on Multitexture mode.