# In blender 2.8 there is no game engine or game logic

Tags: game-engine

I want to design the game in which,when the key press from keyboard then it's should action... For example I want to move  the object with w a s d... How can I use in blender 2.8

Comment: As you've noticed yourself, Blender doesn't come with a game engine anymore. Therefore you will have to use another software to create the game. However you can use Blender to create the models, textures and animations. Game engines that you could potentially use are, e.g. [Godot](https://godotengine.org/), [Unity](https://unity.com/de), [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/) or [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/).

Comment: Why blender doesn't come with a game engine anymore???

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/what-will-happen-with-blender-2-8-game-engine