# Blender Game Engine : resolution scale?

Tags: game-engine

I'm want to make **resolution scale** to my width and height standlone player. It is possible? I can set the width and height by `bge.render` but can I change the resolution scale like other games?

I searched in google and I didn't found anything about this.

Thank You!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972

Comment: I mean in 2.79 or UPBGE 0.2.5. @Duarte Farrajota Ramos♦