# Can I use Blender to set up game logic?

Tags: source-code, encoding

I want to create a game using Blender 2.93. I don't know if I can use Blender to create the game logistics.

I want to create a 3D game that's set up like Minecraft. An almost infinite world that's somewhat based on blocks. I'm not asking for modeling advice. I can do that later. I want to know if and how I can set up a system within Blender that sets spawning of biomes, animals, etc.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/what-will-happen-with-blender-2-8-game-engine

Comment: *logic* or *logistics*? Or both?

Comment: Note that Minecraft uses its own game engine because most game engines are not set up to handle almost-infinite worlds based on blocks. Minecraft is "not like the other games" and engines like Blender are designed to handle the other games. Most games consist of storylines and worlds created by the game designers, and that's what most game engines are designed for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically you might be able to, with a lot of Python scripting & brain power. I would recommend using a real game engine, though, like [Godot](https://godotengine.org/), which has excellent Blender integration.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using UPBGE. So you don't have to "learn" two different systems and it's all inside Blender itself.

You can download it here: https://upbge.org/download

It's for free as Blender and my personal experience with the support/developers was excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Blender can definitely be used to setup levels, tag game objects with properties. Since you mentioned blocks, you can use the remesh modifier set to "blocks mode", so that you can control the blockiness of your game objects.

Then you can export your game levels and objects to other game engines (Godot, Unity).

But as dr.Sybren and Chris mentioned, is will take quite a bit of programming and data adapting to get this done seamlessly and their recommendations are very apt.