# Is Raspberry Pi 4 able to run Blender Game Engine games?

Tags: game-engine, compatibility

Ex. I have a game where my object is floating in some empty space and i can interact with it.
I can zoom in/out, rotate in every direction and do some clicks which cause some animations (for ex. when i click on my object it starts spinning)

Is RPi4 able to run this kind of a simple game?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106972/what-will-happen-with-blender-2-8-game-engine

Comment: There is no official Blender version for Pi

Comment: But here https://upbge.org/#/download i can see Blender Game Engine for Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I do not have experience with Raspberry Pi)

To answer your question kind of... in pieces:

Raspberry Pi 4 natively uses OpenGL ES 3.1, and natively supports OpenGL 2.2 (allegedly).

Although I have found resources that purport to unlocking the Pi 4 to versions of OpenGL as late as roughly 3.3.

It's not entirely clear what OpenGLs the Videocore VI chip is actually capable of, but it seems people are running Blender 2.79b, and games like Open Arena, just fine.

---

In terms of [*does R. Pi 4 have the power*]:           yes (Hardware meets spec)

In terms of [*does R. Pi 4 have the software*]:        yes (Hardware meets reqs)

In terms of [*does R. Pi 4 have the firmware*]:        it seems so (soft yes)

In terms of [*does R. Pi 4 have the API/Middleware*]:  it kind of seems so (maybe)

If you're using Blender 2.79b, and the old vanilla engine within it, and you also are not using any advanced shaders or Eevee (UPBGE), then all signs point to a... :

**Soft Yes**

---

References...

- [Raspberry Pi Engineer re: Officially reported OpenGL version conformance](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=299461#p1801267)
- [Raspberry Pi official site reporting Open Arena performance](https://magpi.raspberrypi.com/articles/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks#:%7E:text=Quake%20III%2Dbased%20OpenArena)
- Blender 2.79b on R. Pi 4 (1): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk0-bae-mDc
- Blender 2.79b on R. Pi 4 (2): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ5jU32sejQ
- Blender 2.79b on R. Pi 4 (3): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQ51Q9Kvz5s

Comment: As an additional: UPBGE 0.2x is built on the Blender 2.79b legacy engine, and MIGHT theoretically also work. But to re-iterate, UPBGE 0.3.0 being OpenGL 3.x will very certainly crash, or not work at all as intended.